# is this loop correct? sometimes it displays extra content (wordpress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I've put together this little loop to display upcoming 4 events from the calendar.

I placed it in sidebar.

On archive page it behaves normally.

But on single post page it goes crazy, and loads 4 events + reloads everything on the page like second sidebar second post and second right sidebar...

Commenting out query stops this insane behavior. So no I didn't make stupid copy paste mistake :)

```
                    <ul class="sidebarlists">
                        <li>
                        <h2>Upcoming Events</h2>
                        <span class="seeallside"><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/events/">See All</a></span>

                            <?php
                                $postslist = query_posts('order=DESC&orderby=modified&posts_per_page=4&post_type=tribe_events&eventDisplay=upcoming'); 

                                echo "<ul>";

                                foreach ($postslist as $loopID => $p) {
                                   echo "<li>";
                                   echo "<a title='". $p->post_title . "' href='" . get_permalink($p->ID) . "'>".get_the_post_thumbnail( $p->ID, array( 50,50, 'class' => ' sidebarthumb '))."</a>";
                                   echo "<h3><a title='". $p->post_title  . "' href='" . get_permalink($p->ID) . "'>".$p->post_title."</a></h3>";
                                   echo "<span>".tribe_get_start_date( $p->ID, true, 'D. M j, Y' )."</span>";
                                   echo " <div class=\"clearfloat\"></div>";
                                   echo "</li>";
                                }

                                echo "</ul>";      
                            ?>

                        </li>
                    <!-- End #sidebarlists --></ul>
```

Comment: only you would now if it it correct or not,

Comment: It looks like your HTML may be messed up. In your loop you have a `<li>` tag and it contains a bunch of other stuff (`<span>` `<div>` etc). You might want to look into that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading here :
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts

it says that you should use "secondary" loops using get_posts(), because query_posts scraps the $post variables
see "Alters Main Loop" AND "Secondary Loops"

Comment: that was fast! Should I use get_post also on archives page where it query_post worked fine?

Comment: The query_posts() is meant for altering the main loop Only... So, if your talking about the archive in the center of the page, you should use query_posts, and else, if this is about sidebars or widgets , get_posts.

Comment: Try to avoid using query_posts altogether and use [WP Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)